# Simplifying a Single Logic Gate With Unknown Values

Tags: c++, logic, bitwise-operators, simplify

I am modeling a system that uses four bit types:

- ZERO: This is the literal value 0
- ONE: This is the literal value 1
- DONTCARE: This means either 0 or 1 is acceptable
- UNKNOWN: Nothing is known about what this bit should be.

Now, I have a simple logic gate taking two inputs and giving one output (AND, OR, NOR, NAND, XOR, etc.).  Any of the bit values could be in any location.

As examples, we might have:

```
1: ZERO NAND ONE = UNKNOWN
2: DONTCARE XOR DONTCARE = UNKNOWN
3: ONE AND DONTCARE = ONE
4: ONE OR UNKNOWN = DONTCARE
5: DONTCARE XOR UNKNOWN = ONE
```

The problem is trying to reduce expressions like that down as much as possible, propagating both directions.  For example, the above can be reduced to:

```
1: ZERO NAND ONE = ONE                  (left to right)
2: DONTCARE XOR DONTCARE = DONTCARE     (left to right)
3: ONE AND ONE = ONE                    (right to left)
4: ONE OR DONTCARE = ONE                (both)
5: DONTCARE XOR UNKNOWN = ONE           (can't do anything)
```

There are a lot of gates, and each gate has 64 (=4^3) possible combinations of inputs.  I have tried various ways of tackling each gate individually, but it is error prone and complex.  What I need is some unified method of reducing all gates.  **My question: how should I do this?**

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Comment: @Blindy the system is being implemented in C++, so if C++ were given in an answer, it would be welcome.

Comment: What system? I only see the homework requirements without any work done at all.

Comment: @Blindy this isn't a homework question. Also, as I wrote, `I have tried various ways of tackling each gate individually, but it is error prone and complex.` I don't know how to approach a general solution, if one even exists. That's the point.